Ubuntu 24.04 does not remember screen position
I have an issue with screen position. I have two monitors (monitor 1 and monitor 2), monitor 1 is primary right in front of me. Monitor 2 is on left side of monitor 1. Whenever I switch from 'Join display' mode to 'single' display mode and back, the position of monitor 2 resets and in display settings is placed on right side of monitor 1, but in reality it is on left side. I have to manually change it again in settings.
Any idea how I can solve the issue?
